# phpmyadmin after login wrong URL

Tags: nginx, phpmyadmin, debian

I have been looking for an answer to this problem but could not find it. So here it is:
Log in page: 
    http://192.168.1.1/phpmyadmin
After loging in it sends me to: 
    http://192.168.1.1/index.php?token=3d99b7b0606c6d60417b9dd2b7a2dc17

I have to add phpmyadmin/ before index.php to enter. After that I can navigate fine, but when I make some changes in phpmyadmin configuration and click Apply it shows an 404 page and I have to type again phpmyadmin after the ip address.

System Linux Debian 8 jessie
Web Server nginx
Default config file:

```
location /phpmyadmin {
        auth_basic "Admin Login";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/pma_pass;
        index index.php;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nginx with phpmyadmin wrong direction on login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37408704/nginx-with-phpmyadmin-wrong-direction-on-login)

Answer (score 1):

Well lokks like I found the problem. There is a bug in nginx:
[bug](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/321?_ga=1.11926064.521854320.1459807988)

the error was in php configuration:

```
try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404;; <- remove this line add the following two:
    if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
        return 404;
    }
```

Hope helps someone.

Comment: Can you add more details? Which file should this be added to, which lines?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I fixed this on Ubuntu.

Edit /etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php

After lines

```
$cfg['UploadDir'] = '';
$cfg['SaveDir'] = '';
```

Add such line with **full absolute path** to your phpmyadmin. Trailing slash is mandatory.

```
$cfg['PmaAbsoluteUri'] = 'http://12.345.67.89/phpmyadmin/';
```

After this my problem with wrong nginx redirection after login was fixed!

Answer (score 1):

From : [Nginx with phpmyadmin wrong direction on login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37408704/nginx-with-phpmyadmin-wrong-direction-on-login)

You can do as simple as editing phpmyadmin config file without overheading NGINX

- Open config.inc.php file 
  `sudo nano /etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php`
- Add the following code to it

  `$cfg['PmaAbsoluteUri'] =  $_SERVER[HTTP_HOST].dirname($_SERVER[SCRIPT_NAME]);`
- Done

Credits : [xaz0r](http://phpmyadmin.996332.n3.nabble.com/phpmyadmin-redirects-to-localhost-on-login-from-web-tp11466p11467.html)

Comment: Please don't copy and paste answers. If the question matches another completely, flag it as a duplicate instead